# Запуск программ на С через консоль с флагами на OS X

Tags: c, xcode, macos

Пытаюсь запустить программу на языке С через маковский терминал с флагом -fsanitize=undefine, но выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
MacBook-1:CS <username>$ gcc -fsanitize=undefined  main.c
ld: file not found:      
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ubsan_osx_dynamic.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Что нужно сделать? У меня в запуске программ через консоль небольшой опыт, так как привык пользоваться Xcode.

Comment: а без `-fsanitize=undefined` собирает?

Comment: Может вы имели в виду сборку, а не запуск?

Comment: Вам же всё пишет компилятор. Он не может найти библиотеку санитайзера. Нужно её установить.

Comment: нет, не компилятор, а линковщик. Но почему он линкует через clang... Может и компилировать попробовать через clang?

Comment: без флага собирает. насколько я понял, компилирует программу clang, но если написать "clang -fsani..." выдает ту же ошибку. а как установить эту библиотеку?